# disable non listed keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 with Gnome 3.34.2

The configured keyboard shortcut for moving workspaces up and down is `Super+Page Up` and `Super+Page Down` 
[image]

Additionally, `ctrl+alt+arrow` also move workspaces. I would like to disable the shortcut `ctrl+alt+arrow` but con't figure out where to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `dconf-editor` and navigate to org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings. There, you can edit the key assignments for `move-to-workspace-down` and `move-to-workspace-up` to remove the keyboard assignment you do not want.