# Disable <Alt><Shift> Left/Right input source change

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

The keyboard combinations `<Alt><Shift>Left` and `<Alt><Shift>Right` switch to the next or previous keyboard input source (eg, English, Spanish, Chinese keyboard layouts).

This shortcut does not appear in the keyboards shortcuts section of Settings. I also tried to follow the instructions from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216826/disable-non-listed-keyboard-shortcut) and installed `dconf-editor`, but was unable to find those shortcuts there.

How can I disable these shortcuts?

Using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: It could be an xkb option. You didn't tell us the Ubuntu version and flavour so I can't tell you how to configure xkb options, but you should be able to find it out on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @danzel.

It turns out that it's where shown below. Was very confused about how `'grp:alt_shift_toggle'` or `'grp_led:scroll'` translates to `<Alt><Shift>Left/Right`.

[image]

Comment: Please note that there may be a need to edit `/etc/default/keyboard` as well.